Variational inference question - how to get eq. 22 from eq. 21
Referring to David Blei's notes on variational inference, I wonder how to get eq. 22 from eq. 21. Also, what is $z_{-k}$ in $L_k = \int q(z_k) \mathbb{E}_{-k}[\log p(z_k | z_{-k},x)]dz_k - \int q(z_k)\log q(z_k) dz_k$
eq. 21: $L_k = E[log p(z_k | z_{-k}, x)] - E_j[log q (z_k)] + const$
eq. 22: $L_k = \int q(z_k) \mathbb{E}_{-k}[\log p(z_k | z_{-k},x)]dz_k - \int q(z_k)\log q(z_k) dz_k$


Please use math typesetting instead of hard-to-read images. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Questions using typesetting are more likely to be answered, and are accessible to people who use screen readers due to visual impairment.
